# ImageView is returning all the wrong values for its bounds

Tags: android, android-layout

```
public class Terrain {

    public Bitmap tile;
    public InputStream is;
    public ObjectAnimator moveLeft;
    public Drawable tileDrawable;
    public Rect bounds;
    public ImageView terrainImage;

    public int top = 0;
    public int bottom = 0;
    public int left = 0;
    public int right = 0;
}
```

And this `TerrainFactory` class I created

```
    public class TerrainFactory {

    public Terrain createNewTerrain(Activity activity, RelativeLayout relativeLayout,
                                            final ArrayList<Terrain> terrainArrayList){

        terrain = new Terrain();
        terrain.is = activity.getResources().openRawResource(+R.drawable.game_tile);
        terrain.tile = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(terrain.is);
        terrain.tileDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(activity.getResources(), terrain.tile);
        terrain.terrainImage = new ImageView(activity);
        terrain.terrainImage.setImageDrawable(terrain.tileDrawable);
        relativeLayout.addView(terrain.terrainImage);

        terrain.terrainImage.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

            public void onGlobalLayout() {

                terrain.left = terrain.terrainImage.getLeft();
                terrain.right = terrain.terrainImage.getRight();
                terrain.bottom = terrain.terrainImage.getBottom();
                terrain.top = terrain.terrainImage.getTop();

                Log.d("Left ", "Bounds are " + terrain.left);
                Log.d("Right ", "Bounds are " + terrain.right);
                Log.d("Bottom ", "Bounds are " + terrain.bottom);
                Log.d("Top ", "Bounds are " + terrain.top);
                terrain.terrainImage.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            }
        });
        return terrain;
    }
}
```

The problem is, when I actually run this, this is what my log tells me :

- Left﹕ Bounds are 0
- Right﹕ Bounds are 200
- Bottom﹕ Bounds are 150
- Top﹕ Bounds are 0

Here's a visual if it's any help :
[image]

Also, I believe the actionbar at the top may have something to do with this, but I'm not quite sure.

It shouldn't be telling me that the top bounds of my image is 0. All four numbers that I got back are all wrong.

Also, I know I shouldn't put two questions in one, but how exactly do I get rid of that annoying 25 pixel margin at the far left? 
I've already tried going into the dimens.xml and setting all the margins to 0dp, but it doesn't seem to fix it.

Not sure if this is relevant, but here's my `PlayActivity.xml`, where everything happens :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.wordpress.somegame.runrun.activity.PlayActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        ></RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**UPDATE :**

It seems that if I create an `ImageView` in the non-nested `RelativeLayout`, it returns the correct numbers, aside from the top side, which is off probably because of the action bar.

However, if I make an image in the nested `RelativeLayout`, I end up getting entirely wrong numbers, so I assume it may have something to do with my XML, perhaps? But I can't seem to figure out why it works for the non-nested `RelativeLayout`, yet doesn't work for the nested `RelativeLayout`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `getLeft()`, `getRight()`, `getBottom()` and `getTop()` return values relative to the parent, not screen coordinates. Since you are adding the `ImageView` to the `RelativeLayout` as a first child with no special layout parameters, it is going to have (top, left) == (0, 0).

For the extra 25 pixels, you can put some colored background on your layouts to see their span; or you could examine the layout dump with ddms. I suspect it is part of your theme. Start setting both the margins and paddings to 0 on your layouts to see if this is the case.

Comment: Then how can I get the ImageView's getLeft(), getRight(), getBottom(), and getTop() relative to its screen coordinates?

Comment: Also, I'm using the default theme.

Comment: try `View.getLocationOnScreen`

Comment: If I understand correctly, that should give me the top left coordinate of the image. But then I would only have the X coordinate of the left side, and the Y coordinate of the top side. How exactly would I get the X coordinate of the right side and the Y coordinate of the bottom?

Comment: We're talking about just a delta at this point, right? You can, for example, use startX + getWidth() to find your bottomX and startY + getHeight() to find your bottomY.

Comment: That's still really odd. getLocationOnScreen is suppoesd to give me the absolute pixel value for the X and Y of the ImageView, but I still get 0 for the left, even though it should be 25. I fully accept that I could just add 25 and get the problem over-with, but I'm dying to know why it won't give me the right number for my left. The right is also off by 25. But the top and bottom bounds are spot on.

Comment: I don't experience the 25 pixels offset you show in the picture. The best way to see where's coming from is (while the app is running) to launch the Android Device Monitor (icon in the toolbar or Tools->Android->Android Device Monitor), select your app and click the `Dump View Hierarchy for UI Automator` button. You will be able to see the bounds for all the views on the screen and figure out where it is coming from

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/Wm9qWKt.png

I don't know how exactly to interpret this data. It doesn't tell me exactly WHERE it comes from. All I know is that there are odd FrameLayouts that I never made there and that the offset happens on the 2nd FrameLayout where it says [0, 38].

Comment: The layout you set on the activity is inserted into a bigger hierarchy that is making up the whole screen. The exact type of layouts could (and do) differ from Android version to Android version. And, as we could see, from device to device. It seems like it thinks there should be some reserved space over there (for the status bar). What should be normal is to be offset on the dimension where the status bar is displayed (that's what happens on my Nexus 5 emulator).  Unfortunately, I don't think you can get rid of that space (on your device) unless you hide the status bar.

Comment: I forgot to mention that you cannot assume that the status bar height is always 25px - it differs from device type to device type.